# Не отображается Panel в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Впервые пишу на Форуме, неужели я ступил на путь Программиста.

Делаю блокнот на WinForms и динамически создаю панели в специальном классе. Создание происходит один раз в начале программы.

```
            // Создание MenuPanel
            MenuPanel = new Panel();
            MenuPanel.Size = new Size(100, 135);
            MenuPanel.Location = new Point(631, 4);
            MenuPanel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
            MenuPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            MenuPanel.BackColor = Color.White;
            MenuPanel.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(34, 40, 49);

            // По началу он не виден и не слышан
            MenuPanel.Enabled = false;
            MenuPanel.Visible = false;

            // Добавление панели на форму
            form.Controls.Add(MenuPanel);
```

По нажатию кнопки эта панель становиться видимой

```
        if (MenuManager.MenuPanel.Enabled == false) // Если спрятан
        {
            // Устанавливаем противоположную видимость
            MenuManager.MenuPanel.Enabled = true;
            MenuManager.MenuPanel.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (MenuManager.MenuPanel.Enabled == true) // Если виден
        {
            MenuManager.SetVisible(false, 
                MenuManager.MenuPanel, 
                MenuManager.SettingsPanel, 
                MenuManager.OpacityPanel);
        }
```

С обработчиком событий все нормально. В дебагере пишется панель становиться видимой и рабочей. Но все равно не отображается на форме. Пробовал использовать BringToFront(); но все равно не помогло. В свойстве Parent у панели есть форма и еще что-то.

> Parent {Writer.Form1, Text.Form1}

> Text — это класс, управляющий richTextBox
> Menu — это класс, управляющий меню (панелями)

Вообще не вдупляю в чем проблема

Comment: Что такое `form`? только не говорите, что форма, это я и так знаю. Смысл в том чтобы понять, форма, которую вы видите на экране и форма, куда добавлен контрол - один и тот же экземпляр класса формы. Но вы не показали код, откуда берутся и куда деваются у вас формы, сделовательно и источник проблемы не ясен.

Comment: Не думаю, что дело в этом. RichTextBox создается таким же образом, но нормально работает. 
В классе есть пустое поле Form1, значения которой присваиваются в конструкторе. В классе Form1 я вызываю конструктор и отправляю "this"

Comment: Ну значит вам виднее.

Comment: Смотрите в дебаггере, где именно в списке контролов формы лежит ваша панель, и там смотрите её текущие параметры.